# android button click and clicked

Tags: android, buttonclick

I am fairly new to android programming (but not to Java programming). I have a use case where a user clicks a 'Go >>' Button. Once the button is clicked, the text on the button changes to 'Done!' and the user can click the same button once he is 'done'.

I am wondering what is the best approach to implement this button behaviour... One approach that I can think of is to check for the button text and trigger appropriate action - is there a better way that you could recommend? Thanks!

Comment: i think you may maintain a triggerCounter in type of integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best" approach is probably to check a boolean flag in the OnClickListener if the Button has already been clicked.

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    boolean isFirstClick = true;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isFirstClick) {
            isFirstClick = false;
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative approach is to check the value of the Buttons' text, but this is a few *milliseconds* slower.